# How to write an email informing management about new qualifications?

Tags: professionalism, management, cover-letter

I have just completed my MSc in Forest Economics and Management. How do I inform my employer of my newly acquired certificate?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a friendly, personal style for all my communications.

To my boss: "Letting you know that I just got my diploma in agric. I hope that this diploma translates in my being able to do more mission-critical tasks for you and fame and fortune (hint, hint) for me :)"

To HR: "Letting you know for your records that I just received my diploma in agribusiness. Proof provided upon request"